# Read Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am writing a web application using c#.net 4.0 to read post in a specific Facebook page.
E.g. http://www.facebook.com/pages/Public-Service-Association/164106710269112

I used Facebook C# SDK from http://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk/

Please help me to read the posts using above SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you read [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)?

Answer (score 0):

After you follow the [tutorial](http://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk/), after you declare a JSON for your results, simple get their Profile Feed:

`Facebook.FacebookAPI api = new Facebook.FacebookAPI(token);  //place your access token`

`JSONObject result = api.Get(@"/nzpsa/feed");`